# popBackStackImmediate() not working

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    View h = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.gohome);
    h.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {    
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Log.w("tt", "tttt");
                    if(MainActivity.fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
                        try {
                            MainActivity.fm.popBackStackImmediate("tiles", 0);
                        }
                        catch(Exception e) {
                            Log.w("tt", "tttt" + e);
                        }
                    }
                    //((MainActivity)arg0.getContext()).toggle();      
                }
            }).start();
        }           
    });
}
```

I have a home button on my app. When clicked, i wanted to return to the fragment names "tiles" which is the bottom most fragment. But this is not working ... plz help

Comment: I am getting the error as "Only the original thread that created the view heirarchy can touch the view"

Comment: ohkk now im not getting this error as i am using runOnUiThread.... but still the fragments are not getting popped :(

Comment: I printed the BackStackEntryCount.... it doesnt seem to change even after popBackStackImmediate...